# Mutual resistance

Tags: resistance

I can easily understand the mutual coupling within an electrical circuit, but the mutual resistive behavior remains incomprehensible to me. Doesn't the mutual inductive coupling model the impact of the neighboring currents?

I would also very much appreciate books or papers elaborating on the matter - I cannot seem to find any.

Comment: I've never heard of mutual resistance.

Comment: @Andyaka Check this out https://verimod.com/presentations/Mutual_Resistance_Rev3.pdf

Comment: I think it's a different way of looking at proximity effect.

Comment: @Andyaka Gave it thought + research. You are right, it's a way to account for proximity effects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is used to model proximity effect between conductors, as @Andy aka stated.

Answer (score 2):

"Electromagnetic Fields and Energy" by Hermann A. Haus and James R. Melcher.